# Need help on query optimization while retrive give Error server not found

Tags: mysql, optimization, group-by

I have query which works fine but now the data is in millions so while fetch it says server not found. What I want here to compare the sale of Previous month of current month and previous month of previous month customer wise so i user group by customer_id .

I see that removing group by query run faster but the output i want customer wise only so it has to be there.

```
SELECT Customer.id, 
       Customer.first_name, 
       Customer.last_name, 
       SUM(Sale.`cal_qty`) AS totPurchase, 
       Sale2.tot2 as totPurchase2 
FROM `customers` AS Customer 
LEFT JOIN `sales` AS Sale 
    ON Sale.customer_id = Customer.id 
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT s2.customer_id AS customer_id, 
           SUM(s2.cal_qty) as tot2 
    FROM sales as s2 
    WHERE s2.sale_date between '2015-07-23' 
        AND '2015-08-21' 
    GROUP BY s2.customer_id 
) AS Sale2 
    ON Sale.customer_id = Sale2.customer_id 
WHERE Sale.sale_date between '2015-08-22' AND '2015-09-21' 
GROUP BY Sale.`customer_id` 
having totPurchase > totPurchase2 
ORDER BY totPurchase DESC
```

Can anyone suggest me optimized query over my query.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure but you can try below query, may be helpful to you-

Note: assuming customer.id is a primary key or indexed, sale.customer_id is also indexed, sale.sale_date is also indexed.

```
SELECT Customer.id, 
       Customer.first_name, 
       Customer.last_name, 
       sale1.totPurchase, 
       Sale2.tot2 AS totPurchase2 
FROM `customers` AS Customer 
JOIN 
(
SELECT Sale.`customer_id`,
       SUM(Sale.`cal_qty`) AS totPurchase 
FROM `sales` AS Sale
WHERE Sale.sale_date BETWEEN '2015-08-22' AND '2015-09-21' 
GROUP BY Sale.`customer_id` 
) AS Sale1 ON Sale1.customer_id = Customer.id 
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT s2.customer_id AS customer_id, 
           SUM(s2.cal_qty) AS tot2 
    FROM sales AS s2 
    WHERE s2.sale_date BETWEEN '2015-07-23' 
        AND '2015-08-21' 
    GROUP BY s2.customer_id 
) AS Sale2 
ON Sale1.customer_id = Sale2.customer_id 
HAVING totPurchase > totPurchase2 
ORDER BY totPurchase DESC
```

Comment: mysql saying " MySQL server has gone away " . i just want to compare same fields with different date range. Thanks.

Comment: r ur field indexed as I mentioned in my post, also try to execute both sub-queries seperately if you are getting results or any error.

Comment: If it helps you then you may accept it as answer by green stick.  :)